# Magento 2: In which phtml file Footer content is defined?

Tags: magento2

I want to remove this class. Can anyone help me out to find out the class ?
[image]

Comment: what you want to do with that one?

Answer (score 1):

You can find that class inside this file

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" ifconfig="design/footer/report_bugs"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

You can update new class using below line

```
<referenceContainer name="footer" htmlClass="your-new-class-name" />
```

You can add above line in your `default.xml` file

Hope this will help you!